# View not updating even the property has changed

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the function that called the API to get the data called `getData()`. I called the function from another component with this way (for the ease of reading, i changed the component name to MainComponent and AnotherComponent):

```
import MainComponent from ./../main-component/main-component

...

export class AnotherComponent extends OnInit {
   ...

   constructor(private _maincomp: MainComponent){}

   onClick = () => {
      this._maincomp.getData();
   }
}
```

When I checked the data within the property of MainComponent, it's already changed, but the view isn't. How can I solve that?

Here is the html on the MainComponent:

```
<div class="row table-container shadow rounded mt-4 ml-1">
   <table mat-table class="data-table mat-elevation-z10" [dataSource]="datas">
       <ng-container matColumnDef="Order ID">
           <mat-header-cell class="header order-id-col" *matHeaderCellDef>Order ID</mat-header-cell>
           <mat-cell class="order-id-col col-data" *matCellDef="let data">{{ data.order_id }}</mat-cell>
       </ng-container>

       //another ng-container goes here...

       <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
       <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></mat-row>
   </table>
</div>
```

and this is the .ts file of MainComponent:

```
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

   displayedColumns = ['Order ID', 'Order By', 'Batch Kultur', 'Jenis Media', 'Jenis Vessel', 'Jumlah Ordered',
                    'Tanggal Order', 'Tanggal Pakai', 'Status', 'Action'];
   datas;
   filter;

   constructor(private _service: DataModelService) { }

   ngOnInit() {
       this.getData();
   }

   getData = () => {
       this._service.getData(1, 10, this.filter , 'media-request')
                .subscribe(
                    res => {
                        this.datas = res.data.data;
                    },
                    err => {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                );
   }  
}
```

and this it the AnotherComponent that called the function in MainComponent:

```
import { MainComponent } from '../main-component/main-component.component';

export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public _maincomp: MainComponent) { }

  ngOnInit() {}


  onClick = () => {
      this._router.navigate([`dashboard/main-component`]);

      setTimeout(() => {
        this._maincomp.getData();
      }, 1000)
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to add source of `MainComponent` as well as `@Component()` annotations of both.

Comment: @muradm how can i do that?

Comment: Just edit your question and add them to the question. It is not enough information to understand and evaluate your question.

Comment: Why not creating `getData()` as a method on a service?

Comment: please provide `html` and `ts` code in detail.what are you trying and where is the issue in code.

Comment: i provide the html and ts as simple as possible. thank you @muradm

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ChangeDetectorRef`:

```
constructor(
  private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
  private _maincomp: MainComponent
) {}

onClick = () {
  this._maincomp.getData();
  this.cdRef.detectChanges();
}
```